# Условие WHERE внутри JSON поля postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

В базе есть записи

```
id :  3024 
data : ["Егор","[{\"text\":\"  Центральноафриканская Республика  CAF  \",\"value\":\"2696\"}]"]

id : 3025
data : ["Олег","[{\"text\":\"  Египет  \",\"value\":\"3341\"}]"]
```

Как сделать запрос, чтобы выбрать только записи со значением value 
2696 (Центральноафриканская Республика)
которые находятся внутри JSON записи поля data?

Comment: Хотелось бы иметь возможность оперировать в JSON сущности, а не простой строки. То есть искать по ключам, проходить циклом и.т.д.

Comment: http://schinckel.net/2014/05/25/querying-json-in-postgres/ т.е. в теории вам поможет поиск типа `data @> '{"value":2696}'`

Comment: Нет, там JSON это массив, внутри него есть строки есть массивы, внутри массивов объект у которого как раз text и value ключи.

Comment: @manking, так что такое `data` на самом деле? лучше сразу готовый вывод DDL... и что мешает перевести его в postgres'овский встроенный JSON?

Comment: В этой конкретной задаче проще искать в строке. Так как порядок в массиве и вложенность может меняться и неизвестная. То есть нужен или полный проход по всему JSON либо только вот поиск в строке.